# FileOptions extension in multiple protos

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to utilize file level extension using **FileOptions** to version some proto files.

I created following files:

**Version.proto**

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
extend google.protobuf.FileOptions {
  string version = 50001;
}
```

I have two additional protos that import Version.proto and use option(version) extension:

**A.proto**

```
import "Version.proto";
option (version) = "1.0.1";
```

**B.proto**

```
import "Version.proto";
option (version) = "1.0.1";
```

I compile proto files with protoc.exe and link libprotobufd.dll. When I run the application that utilize A & B files I got following error:

*[libprotobuf FATAL google\protobuf\extension_set.cc:102] **Multiple extension registrations for type google.protobuf.FileOptions**, field number 50001.*

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how it's happening without knowing how your project is structured/being compiled, but you are somehow using the field number 50001 more than once. Double check that the number 50001 only shows up in your project once. If you have multiple FileOptions messages floating around, they all share the same message extension field numbers.

If you're pretty sure that you're not registering `50001` twice, then try switching to something random like `78354` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I tried different numbers but didn't help. As far as I understand the issue, first time the number is reserved in **A.proto** when **Version.proto** is imported and then in **B.proto**, during the import also.

Comment: My setup: C++ VS 2017, protobuf ver 3.4.0. Protos are compiled by protoc.exe, output files are included into the project. Protobuf.dll linked dynamically.

Comment: @GrzesiekMal are you compiling all of them at the same time?

Comment: yes, all at once. The issue has some more details here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6029